# SortedSet mapped on Hibernate using @Orderby by Inherited field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the entity Alpha, and inside them:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "alpha")
@OrderBy("attributeName ASC")
@Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL)
private SortedSet<Beta> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Beta>();
```

The entity Beta Inherits from entity Gamma.
Gamma have "attributeName" as attribute.

If i use a attribute of Beta, works fine. But when i use the inherited attribute, the hibernate tries to look for the attributeName attribute in the Beta class, which in fact does not exist.

Follow the exception:

```
could not initialize a collection: [...sortedSet]
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection: [...sortedSet]
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "GAMA"."GAMA_NM_ATT": invalid identifier
```

**EDIT1:**
Alpha, Beta and Gama are Tables in my Database.

I can't use @MappedSuperClass in Gama because it's a Table.

briefly entity declarations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GAMA")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_GAM_CD_GAMA", sequenceName = "SQ_GAM_CD_GAMA")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Gama implements IEntity<Long> {

    @Column(name = "GAM_NM_ATT", nullable = false, length = 260)
    public String getAttributeName() {
        return this.attributeName;
    }
...
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BETA")
public class Beta extends Gama implements Comparable<Beta> {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BET_CD_BETA", nullable = false)
    public Alpha getAlpha() {
        return alpha;
    }
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ALPHA")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_ALP_CD_ALPHA", sequenceName = "SQ_ALP_CD_ALPHA")
public class Alpha implements IEntity<Long> {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "alpha")
    @Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL)
    @Orderby("attributeName ASC")   //<------------ **PROBLEM**
    private SortedSet<Beta> betaSortedSet = new TreeSet<Beta>();
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell what may be wrong without a [mcve].  Moreover, your interpretation of the nature of the problem does not seem to line up with the exception presented.

Comment: Are you using [`@MappedSuperclass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html)?

Comment: do you use @MappedSuperclass on the Gamma?

Comment: Anyway, do you really need the `@OrderBy` at all, since you're mapping the relationship as a `SortedSet`?

Comment: Without this problematic line, works "fine", except that the collection is ordered by jvm always that i get on hibernate queries.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

I think you can try use `@Formula`.

For example:

Map in `Beta` a new attribute annoted with `@Formula("GAM_NM_ATT")` and use this on your `@Orderby`.
In this case it works becose the column is not ambiguous.

Cheers.

Comment: Maybe `@Formula("GAM_NM_ATT")` not work on this way, because Hibernate use `MAIN_TABLE_.GAM_NM_ATT`. You can try with subselect.